# Can you get on an Amtrak train at a later station?

Tags: amtrak

If I buy an Amtrak ticket from say Pontiac, MI to Chicago, can I get on the train at Detroit (three short stations down) if I happen to be closer to Detroit at departure time?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Technically, this is not allowed.  The [Amtrak Terms of Transportation](http://www.amtrak.com/servlet/ContentServer?c=Page&pagename=am%2FLayout&cid=1241337896121) states:

> If you do not board your train as booked, your entire reservation is subject to cancellation.

However, you can call Amtrak and try to change your reservation from Pontiac to Detroit.  You may even get a partial refund if the fare would be less.

Comment: Weird, I was told by the conductor I could get on anywhere between Pontiac and Chicago.

Answer (score 1):

For the best answer to that question, call 1-800-USA-RAIL (800-872-7245).

Second best, http://www.amtrak.com/contact-us. (but do us all a favor, and **don’t** ask “Julie“)